# getting error while cross-compiling util-linux library for android

Tags: c, linux, android-ndk

I am cross compiling util-linux library for android using arm-linux-androideabi.

I created the toolchain and executing the configure statement as 
    ./configure --prefix=/opt/android --build=${BUILD} --host=arm-linux-androideabi  --disable-rpath --without-util --without-ncursesw --without-ncurses --without-tinfo

After doing make i am getting following errors.

```
/u/CC/android-ndk-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/fcntl.h:49:13: warning: redundant redeclaration of 'fcntl' [-Wredundant-decls]
In file included from libblkid/src/topology/sysfs.c:17:0:
/u/CC/android-ndk-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/unistd.h:143:12: note: previous declaration of 'fcntl' was here
In file included from ./include/blkdev.h:11:0,
                 from ./libblkid/src/blkidP.h:34,
                 from libblkid/src/topology/topology.h:4,
                 from libblkid/src/topology/sysfs.c:21:
/u/CC/android-ndk-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/sys/ioctl.h:39:12: warning: redundant redeclaration of 'ioctl' [-Wredundant-decls]
In file included from libblkid/src/topology/sysfs.c:17:0:
/u/CC/android-ndk-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/unistd.h:144:12: note: previous declaration of 'ioctl' was here
  CCLD     libblkid.la
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-config.o: multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-evaluate.o: multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-save.o: multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-blkdev.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-env.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-pager.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-parse-date.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-path.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-randutils.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-strutils.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-timeutils.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-ttyutils.o): multiple definition of '_POSIX_VDISABLE'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-pager.o): previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-exec_shell.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-plymouth-ctrl.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libcommon.a(libcommon_la-langinfo.o): multiple definition of 'l'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: libblkid/src/.libs/libblkid_la-cache.o: previous definition here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:5414: recipe for target 'libblkid.la' failed
make[2]: *** [libblkid.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/u/CC/util-linux-2.31'
Makefile:11990: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/u/CC/util-linux-2.31'
Makefile:5002: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It already points on the error, you need to go to that redundant redcalartion and see why it’s complaints?

Answer (score 0):

First warnings about redeclarations are due to broken NDK headers. Until "unified headers" they're  blindly declaring `fcntl()`, `ioctl()` (and maybe something more) directly from `<fcntl.h>` and `<unistd.h>` with no checking if they are declared already. Unified headers do it in the right way, and are available since NDK r14, see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md).

About second problem - you might have something called `l` and `_POSIX_VDISABLE` accidentaly defined as global variable or function. Looks like some problem in build scripts. Would be nice to see actual compiler / linker commands.